# Sample message structure for Twilio A2P 10DLC Campaign submissions - bracket types and template text examples

Tags: twilio, sms, messaging, twilio-api

For Twilio A2P 10DLC campaign submissions, do the sample template messages have to use square brakets per the examples in the docs, or can we use other brackets?  Just want to know if we have to reformat all of our templates or not before submitting.

Can we use our template field text, or do we have to put in type examples.. ie [123-456-7890] instead of {{location_phone}}

**Example of a template SMS from my app**:
`Your appointment with {{company_name}} - {{location_name}} is at {{time_and_date}}. Please arrive 5 mins early to get checked in. Call {{location_phone}} with questions.`

From Twilio docs:  https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/11847054539547-A2P-10DLC-Campaign-Approval-Best-Practices

**Text and Sample from that doc:**
If you wish to send templated messages, please make sure to indicate the templated fields in sample messages with brackets, to help reviewers better identify which parts are templated

For example, please write `“Dental check due for [Mary Doe], Visit [www.contoso.com] to schedule an appointment or call [123-456-7890]”`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the review is done by humans. I've applied for a few campaigns and got approved, and I just used the brackets ('[', ']').

as below.
ex: Your OTP code is [6-Didigt].

But, I recommend you follow the guideline.